# What must be done to make net5.0 usable in Visual Studio Community Mac 2019 for VB.NET console projects?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-mac

I want to write a cross-platform console application in VB.NET using Visual Studio Community Mac 2019 [VSCM2019]. It has to be able to be run on all platforms that dotnet 5.x currently supports.

When I create a new VB.NET console application in VSCM2019 it defaults to NET Frameworks 4.8 or lower. When I try to change that to net5.x in the project properties, net5.x is not offered in the dropdown list despite the fact that I have installed the latest dotnet 5 sdk.

Is it the case that I must select net5.x when creating the project? If so, where is this done for VB.NET console applications?

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/?view=vsmac-2019 VB isn't supported in VS for Mac ?

Comment: VB in Visual Studio for Mac does not have good support. The .NET 5 and .NET Core 3.1 project templates for VB.NET are shown only if the VBNetDotnetCoreTemplates feature switch is enabled - which you can do via the terminal - `export MD_FEATURES_ENABLED=VBNetDotnetCoreTemplates` and then run VS Mac from the same terminal window `open -n "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"`. An alternative is to use dotnet net from the command line to create the project template. However VS Mac has no code completion for VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not VB.NET is supported or not, I managed to hack it into submission. I created a net5 C# project, renamed the `.csproj` file to `.vbproj` and replaced the `.cs` file with a `.vb` file. Instead of opening VS via the `.sln` file, I opened it via the `.vbproj` file. It compiled and ran and the project properties reflected the change to VB.NET. I then replaced the `.sln` by saving the project.